# Stream Movies from HDD on Rpi To Android Device via Rpi Access Point

Tags: streaming-video

So basically I want to create an ecosystem where I connect a HDD to my Rpi and. The HDD has movies on it. Then I want to create a hotspot on the Rpi and then let upto 8 Android Devices connect to it. Finally, I want to let the users to be able to watch the movies on their phones which is connected to the Rpi.
I am using a Rpi-B with Raspbian Stretch.
I am facing various issues, the most annoying one being that the RPI is not able to create access point with the tutorials present online. Also, I my preferred mode of programming language is Python-3

Comment: What is the question you are asking?  Try and make your question much more specific and include what you have tried and what results you got,   As further comment: Streaming different movies simultaneously to multiple devices is likely to be a huge push for the Pi.  Streaming a single movie at SD type resolution would be an ask using the built-in WiFi.  The only way this might work would be with highly compressed video being buffered and decoded on the clients - Even then getting it to work for 8 users at a time is ambitious.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.